# Problem with Redux Toolkit error handling

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have created an endpoint to fetch user data and got my app configured. It works well but need to ask is there any way to create global error handler? For example if error `status === 400` for any request I want to redirect user to external website.

```
const headers = {
  Accept: 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};

const baseUrl = '/api';

const createRequest = (url, method) => ({ url, method, headers });

export const userApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'userApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getUser: builder.query({
      query: () => createRequest('/user/get', 'GET'),
    }),
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this by the following way. Wrap the error handler on baseQuery.

```js
const headers = {
  Accept: 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};

const baseUrl = '/api';

const createRequest = (url, method) => ({ url, method, headers });

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl });

const baseQueryErrHandler = async (
    args,
    api,
    extraOptions
) => {
    let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
    if(result.error) {
      // capture your error here
     }
     return result
}
export const userApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'userApi',
  baseQuery: baseQueryErrHandler,
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getUser: builder.query({
      query: () => createRequest('/user/get', 'GET'),
    }),
  }),
});
```

However this would help us only to throw exception on console, to show proper toast message to the user we can use the error property from `useQuery`

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#using-fetchbasequery

Answer (score -1):

You can make a common request file, and use that file for each request call and in catch you can set logic for redirection if error code is 400. We are using same way to handle unauthorized user request.

Here is basic code,

```
import axios from 'axios';

const request = (method = 'get', url, requestPayload = {}) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  const preparedRequest = {
    method,
    url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}${url}`,
    data: requestPayload,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  };
  axios(preparedRequest)
    .then((data) => resolve(data.data))
    .catch((err) => {
      if (err.response?.status === 401) {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        window.location.href = '/login';
      }
      reject(err);
    });
});

export default request;
```

You can override this function as per your requirements.

Comment: can i pass this as a function to builder query?